# Inserting Terms into a Polynomial with Degree in descending order. (JAVA)

Tags: java, methods

For my assignment I need to create a Polynomial Class using an ArrayList that consists of Term's (a class that we created earlier in the class, ex: 7x^5). I need to make it so that when the terms are inserted into the ArrayList they are sorted in descending order.

Here is my code:

```
public void insert(Term aTerm)
{
    Term tempTerm = new Term(0,0); //term of 0x^0 that is used to set the term to 0 after its added.

    if(aTerm == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The inserted term cannot be null.");
    else if(aTerm.isZero() == true)
        aTerm.degree(); //PLACEHOLDER not sure what to do here in order to not insert aTerm
    else if(aTerm.degree() > theAL.get(0).degree()) 
        theAL.add(0, aTerm); //adds to position 0 if largest degree
    else if(aTerm.degree() < theAL.get(theAL.size() - 1).degree())
        theAL.add(theAL.size() - 1, aTerm); //adds to the last position if it is the smallest degree
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < theAL.size(); i++)
        {
            if(aTerm.isZero() == true)
                i = theAL.size(); //ends the for loops whenever aTerm is added and set = to 0
            else if(aTerm.degree() < theAL.get(i).degree() && aTerm.degree() > theAL.get(i + 1).degree())
            {
                theAL.add(i + 1, aTerm);  //adds between 2 terms if less than 1st term and greater than 2nd term.
                aTerm.multiplyBy(tempTerm); //makes the term = zero so that the for loop can end after being added.
            }
            else if(aTerm.degree() == theAL.get(i).degree())
            {
                aTerm.addIn(theAL.get(i)); //adds into the term if the degrees are equal
                aTerm.multiplyBy(tempTerm);//makes the term = zero so that the for loop can end after being added.
            }
        }

}
```

If the term is 0 I don't want it added into the Polynomial, but as you can see in my code I'm not really sure what I should do there in order to NOT insert it, so I just put a placeholder there. Any ideas what I should do there?

When I put my code through my Instructors tester it just throws a bunch of OutOfBoundsException's whenever it try's to add terms.

I understand what an OutOfBoundsException is but I'm not sure whats causing it to go out of bounds in every single scenario. I know my code probably needs a lot of work but if anyone could give me some advice I would really appreciate it. I struggled a lot trying to figure out a way to put this together, especially when I got to the part where I use the for loop to traverse through the polynomial.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Term Class:

```
public class Term implements TermInterface

//-------data
private int coefficient;
private int power;


//------constructors
//default constructor
public Term()
{
    this.coefficient = 2;
    this.power = 3;
}
//parameterized constructor
public Term(int aCoefficient, int aPower)
{
    this.coefficient = aCoefficient;
    this.power = aPower;
}
//copy constructor
public Term(Term aTerm)
{
    if(aTerm != null)
        {
        this.coefficient = aTerm.coefficient;
        this.power = aTerm.power;
        }
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Term cannot be null");
}

//------methods

// toString() - returns its representation as a String   3x^2   for example,
    public String toString()
    {
        if(this.coefficient == 0)
            return "0";
        else if(this.power == 0)
            return(this.coefficient + "");
        else if(this.coefficient == 1 && this.power == 1)
            return "x";
        else if(this.coefficient == -1 && this.power == 1)
            return "-x";
        else if(this.power == 1)
            return(this.coefficient + "x");
        else if(this.coefficient == 1)
            return("x^" + this.power);
        else if(this.coefficient == -1)
            return("-x^" + this.power);
        else
            return(this.coefficient + "x^" + this.power);
    }

//degree -  if coefficient is 0, then (it is a constant so) returns 0.
//                  else returns the power

public int degree() 
{
    if(this.coefficient == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return power;
}

//evaluate - evaluates with whatever double is received
public double evaluate(double value)
{
    return Math.pow(value, power) * this.coefficient;
}

//derivative -  return a new Term that is the derivative.   The derivative
//                      is calculated by:
//                          the coefficient of the derivative is the original coefficient times the power
//                          the power of the derivative is the original power minus 1
public Term derivative()
{
    Term derivative = new Term(this.coefficient * this.power, this.power - 1);
    return derivative;
}

//addIn: add another Term to itself.
//The Term that is received is not changed.
//  if the Term that is received is null, throw a new IllegalArgumentException(<your descriptive String here>)
//  if the powers are not the same, throw a new IllegalArgumentException(<your descriptive String here>)
public void addIn(Term anotherTerm)
{
    if(anotherTerm == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Term cannot be null");
    else if(this.power != anotherTerm.power)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Powers must be equial");
    else
        this.coefficient += anotherTerm.coefficient;        
}

//multiplyBy: multiply itself by anotherTerm - result is a new Term that is created and returned.
//The original Term and the Term that is received are not changed.
//  if the Term that is received is null, throw a new IllegalArgumentException(<your descriptive String here>)
public Term multiplyBy(Term anotherTerm)
{
    if(anotherTerm != null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Term cannot be null");
    else
    {
        Term multiplied = new Term(this.coefficient * anotherTerm.coefficient, this.power + anotherTerm.power);
        return multiplied;
    }

}

public boolean isZero()
{
    if(this.coefficient == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//equals: returns true if it is the same as what is received.
//      If both coefficients are 0, they are automatically equal
//      otherwise, both coefficients AND both exponents must be the same
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Term objTerm = (Term)obj;

    return(this.power == objTerm.power && this.coefficient == objTerm.coefficient);
}
```

}

Edit 2:
Final working code:

```
public void insert(Term aTerm)
{   
    if(aTerm == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The inserted term cannot be null.");
    else if(aTerm.isZero() == true)
        return;

    int insertIndex = -1;
    int i = 0;
    boolean degreeEqual = false;

    while(insertIndex == -1 && i < theAL.size())
    {
        Term tempTerm = theAL.get(i);
        if(tempTerm.degree() == aTerm.degree())
        {
            degreeEqual = true;
            aTerm.addIn(tempTerm);
            insertIndex = i;
        }
        else if(aTerm.degree() > tempTerm.degree())
            insertIndex = i;//ends the loop because we know where to put insert the term
        i++; //increment index counter
    }

    if(degreeEqual == false)
    {
        if(insertIndex >= 0) //check to make sure index location is valid.
            theAL.add(insertIndex, aTerm);
        else
            theAL.add(aTerm);//insert term at the end because it is less than other terms
    }
    else
    {
        if(insertIndex >= 0) //check to make sure index location is valid.
        {
            theAL.remove(insertIndex);
            theAL.add(insertIndex, aTerm);
            if(theAL.get(insertIndex).isZero())
            {
                theAL.remove(insertIndex);
            }
        }
        else
            theAL.add(aTerm);//insert term at the end because it is less than other terms
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your Term class too, please? Also, what type is `theAL`?

Comment: I edited in the Term class. theAL is an ArrayList

Comment: Thanks, ok so `theAL` is just a list of Term elements, right?

Comment: Yes it is an ArrayList that contains Term elements. Right now I'm trying to understand what @lolynns did with their code before trying to implement it in my code and see how it works. I'll report back when I've done that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see where you're going with this, but you've made your testing and looping far more complex than need be. I could be misinterpreting the intent of the algorithm, but I would simplify down to something like this:

```
if(aTerm == null || aTerm.isZero()) {
    return;// this is not a valid term
}

int insertIndex = -1; 
int i = 0;
boolean addToList = true;
// loop until you've found your place, make sure to test for end conditions 
// so you don't hit an IndexOutOfBounds error or create an infinite loop
while(insertIndex == -1 && i < theAL.size() && addToList) {
    Term thisTerm = theAL.get(i);
    if(aTerm.degree() == thisTerm.degree()) {
        thisTerm.addIn(aTerm);
        addToList = false;
    } else if(aTerm.degree() > thisTerm.degree()) {
        insertIndex = i;// this will end the loop, we know where to sort 
                        // this element in our array
    }
    i++;// increment our counter
}

if(addToList) {
    // make sure we found a valid location, if so, add in our term
    if(insertIndex >= 0) {
        theAL.add(insertIndex, aTerm);
    } else {
        theAL.add(aTerm); // insert the term at the end, it's less than all 
                          // other terms in the list, or the list is empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it seems to have a race condition when the list is empty. With your code, nothing would be added then (you can never populate the list).

Comment: @Alex You're right, saw it after I published it, fixed now.

Comment: I also think there is another error in this line `if(thisTerm.degree() > aTerm.degree() {` (first of all a missing closing brace) where you check for `>`. In this case, you always add "smaller" elements before greater elements (wrong order).

Comment: @Alex Haha you're editing the same things as I'm going. Check my last update.

Comment: Thanks @lolynns the code works and is a lot more efficient than mine. The only thing is I need to addIn, rather than insert,  the term if its degree matches any terms in the ArrayList. I tried: if(aTerm.degree() == theAL.get(insertIndex).degree() && insertIndex >= 0)
   theAL.get(insertIndex).addIn(aTerm); but I get the out of bounds error again and I'm not sure why. I'm not sure how to format comments as I'm new to Stackoverflow so I'm sorry if this is hard to read

Comment: @Sauromayne I'm not sure what you mean by addIn? The way this algorithm works is if a degree matches one in the list, it will go at the end of all the degrees that are the same. For example if your list is {3x^7, 4x^2, 6x^2, 5x^1} and you want to add 2x^2, it will add it at index 3, after 6x^2 and before 5x^1. Does that achieve what you need?

Comment: No it needs to use the terms class "addIn" method to add it in. For Example: {3x^7, 4x^2, 6x^2, 5x^1} Would need to be {3x^7, 10x^2, 5x^1} It also needs to remove the term if the coefficient becomes 0. I guess I wasn't clear on that and I was hoping I would be able to figure out how to do that on my own but I've been trying different things for the past 20 minutes and getting very lost

Comment: Ahhhh I see now. I have updated the code above to include a conditional for matching degrees. This means we won't necessarily add an element to the array, so we now need an additional boolean to set if a term shouldn't be added. Another way to do this would be a for loop, and then break when you've found your location, but I know some CS profs are super anti-breaks, so I stuck with the while loop.

Comment: Thanks @lolynns . I still have to add it In though so it just needs to be added into the existing term. I edited my post with the final working code that I was able to get with your help, if you get a chance can you take a look at tell me where I could have been more efficient? Edit: I'm seeing your edits now with the addIn

Comment: @Sauromayne and kudos to you for not directly copying my code, but instead figuring out what it did and writing your own code. Keep up the good work. Please mark my answer as accepted when you have a mo

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this line causes some problems:

```
else if(aTerm.degree() < theAL.get(i).degree() && aTerm.degree() > theAL.get(i + 1).degree())
```

You try to access the `i + 1` element of your list. Because of your iterations walks over:

```
for(int i = 0; i < theAL.size(); i++)
```

this will cause a memory access "one greater the list size" and therefore an OutOfBoundException. Just my guess till you can share your Term class. It could also be a problem when the list is empty (before the first element is inserted) because you access the `0` element of the list which does not exist.

For your other question according to the null Term:

```
else if(aTerm.isZero() == true)
    aTerm.degree();
```

you could just `return`:

```
else if(aTerm.isZero() == true)
    return;
```

and do nothing if there is nothing to do.

Comment: So if we have a Polynomial [9x^6, 5x^5, 3x^2, and 7x^1] and the term is 2x^4, the term being inserted needs to go in between 5x^5 and 3x^2. I'm not really sure how I should go about coding that. The line you specified was my attempt. but after looking at it again I don't think it will work. Any ideas on how I can solve this? (Edits because of accidentally hitting enter)